# If statement to change text colour

Tags: actionscript-3

```
for(var temp:int = 0;temp<recipeNum;temp++)
{
    if ((temp == 1) || (temp == 2) || (temp == 6) || (temp == 9))   
    {
        textRecipe.textColor = 0x0000FF;
    }
    else
    {
        textRecipe.textColor = 0x000000;
    }

    textRecipe.text += "\n" + recipe[temp];
    addChild(textRecipe);                   
}
```

The problem with this code all the text on screen is black. I want temp 1,2,6,9 to be blue, any solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong you're using only one `TextField` named `textRecipe`.

Note that, **even if you add it** `recipeNum` **times to the stage**, it's always the same object.

Assigning `textColor` property, it modifies the color of the entire text, so the last color assigned (probably black) will be the color of the entire text.

Either use more than one `TextField` or use a `TextFormat` to assign color to a part of the text:

```
var myFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.color = 0x0000FF;

textRecipe.setTextFormat(myFormat, 5, 8);  //sets color blue to chars from 5 to 8
```

Let me know if you need more help.